# How to find source of Timer thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have a big project that also use many libraries. With jstack I found that there are threads like:

```
Timer-2, Timer-3, Timer-4....
```

and all that jstack can me display is:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x1a013c24> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is it possible to find a class where these threads where created?

Comment: It seems like a pool-tread. The question is finding who is adding tasks to execute to this pool-tread.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/ThreadenumerateThreadtarray.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Timer threads are created by the [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

If you are able to use the debugger you should be able to set a breakpoint in the Timer constructors and find out the source.

Comment: I think, may be possible use AspectJ?

Answer (score 2):

Run your code in a debug environment, and put a breakpoint on the Thread constructors.

Comment: This is a problem, thread created by one of the libraries - I need found which.

Comment: Under the debugger you would be able to see when any of those libraries create the thread.

Comment: user710818, if you have a breakpoint on Thread creation (constructors), you should be able to see which standard library "spawns" the Thread.